# Construct a sequence of real numbers that has a subsequence that converge to $x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Construct a sequence $\alpha$ of real numbers with the property that, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a subsequence of $\alpha$ that converges to $x$.

Comment: It is the same to enumerate a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Do you know one of these?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Ian's comment is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

We will omit the very carefully part in order to concentrate on the idea.

Walk taking steps of length $1/2$ from $0$ to $1$. Then walk backwards taking steps of length $1/3$ all the way to $-1$. Then walk forwards taking steps of length $1/4$ all the way to $2$. Then walk backwards taking steps of length $1/5$ all the way to $-2$. Then forwards in steps of length $1/6$ all the way to $3$. And so on.